# detect clicking different index of the same class or element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexing

I have a navigation with ul li in it

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="zero"></li>
    <li id="one"></li>
    <li id="two"></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

for javascript I have event handler to detect the index I click on. But how do I write a if condition if the current click on the li is different from the previous one?

```
$('li').click(function(){
  var indexNum = $(this).index();
  if( prevIndexNum != currentIndexNum ){
  //do something 
  }
})
```

I guess this is more of a question on how to store the previous variable value? Any read on it greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to save off the last one clicked.

```js
var prevIndexNum;

$('li').click(function() {
  var indexNum = $(this).index();
  if (prevIndexNum !== indexNum) {
    console.log('different');
    prevIndexNum = indexNum;
  } else {
    console.log('same');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="zero">zero</li>
  <li id="one">one</li>
  <li id="two">two</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
var prev
    if(indexNum != prev)
          prev = $(this).index()
```

before.

As the other guy mentioned all you really have to do is save the value from the previous run through the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the the current index in local variable, if the codition is true which is not equal, move the current index to the  global variable which we are going to called prevIndexNum. I hope it will help you a lot.

```
var prevIndexNum;
$('li').click(function(){
  var currentIndexNum = $(this).index();
  if( prevIndexNum != currentIndexNum ){
     //do something if the value are not the same.
  } else {
     // do something if the value are the same.
  }
})
```